# Keras Conv3d input channels conflict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I am creating a network in TF2 that includes conv3D layers.
Here is mY network definition

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        numOutputClasses=None,
        filters1=128,
        filters2=256,
        filters3=512,
    ):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=REGULARISATIONSCALE)
        self.convblock1 = convBlock(filters1, self.regularizer)
        self.convblock2 = convBlock(filters2, self.regularizer)
        self.convblock3 = convBlock(filters3, self.regularizer)
        
    def call(
        self,
        x
       ):

        x = tf.reshape(x, [batchsize, vsize, vsize, vsize, VOXELFEATUREDIM])
        print("input to convbloc1 has shape ", x.shape)
        x = self.convblock1(x)
        print("input to convbloc2 has shape ", x.shape)
        x = self.convblock2(x)
        print(" input to cb3 has shape ", x.shape)
        x = self.convblock3(x)
        return x
```

Where the `convBlock` is defined as

```
class convBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, regularizer):
        super(convBlock, self).__init__()
        self.regularizer = regularizer
        self.conv3d = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                layers.Conv3D(
                    filters=filters,
                    kernel_size=[3, 3, 3],
                    padding="same",
                    strides=[1, 1, 1],
                    bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                    kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                    bias_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                ),
                layers.BatchNormalization(),
                layers.LeakyReLU(),
            ]
        )
        self.maxpool = layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=[2, 2, 2], strides=[2, 2, 2])

    def call(self, x):
        print("in cb")
        print("x shape ", x.shape)
        x = self.conv3d(x)
        print("x shape ", x.shape)
        x = self.conv3d(x)
        print("x shape ", x.shape)
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        print("op shape ", x.shape)
        return x
```

My input to the `Model` has shape(after first reshape) `[32, 16, 16, 16, 128]` which is fed to the first `ConvBlock` layer. As expected the output has shape of `[32, 8, 8, 8, 128]`(with 128 output channels+MaxPool for halving the dimension).
When this output gets fed to `convblock2`(the second convblock in `Model`), the output after first `conv3d` layer is `[32, 8, 8, 8, 256]`(expected - Dimension preserving+256 output channels).
But when this output is passed to second `conv3d` layer of `convblock2` it returns a value error

```
ValueError:expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 128 but received input with shape [32, 8, 8, 8, 256]
```

Now my doubt is why conv3D expecting for number of input channels? Am I missing something in my code?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **UPDATE**

I realized that the `self.conv3d` was a single object being called for two different 3D convolutions with different input channel requirements.
Hence I initialized two different copies of same layer viz. `self.conv3d1` and `self.conv3d2` with exact same architecture. Now my `convBlock` looks like -

```
class convBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, regularizer):
        super(convBlock, self).__init__()
        self.regularizer = regularizer
        self.conv3d1 = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                layers.Conv3D(
                    filters=filters,
                    kernel_size=[3, 3, 3],
                    padding="same",
                    strides=[1, 1, 1],
                    bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                    kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                    bias_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                ),
                layers.BatchNormalization(),
                layers.LeakyReLU(),
            ]
        )
        self.conv3d2 = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                layers.Conv3D(
                    filters=filters,
                    kernel_size=[3, 3, 3],
                    padding="same",
                    strides=[1, 1, 1],
                    bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                    kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                    bias_regularizer=self.regularizer,
                ),
                layers.BatchNormalization(),
                layers.LeakyReLU(),
            ]
        )
        self.maxpool = layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=[2, 2, 2], strides=[2, 2, 2])

    def call(self, x):
        print("in cb")
        print("x shape ", x.shape)
        x = self.conv3d1(x)
        print("x shape ", x.shape)
        x = self.conv3d2(x)
        print("x shape ", x.shape)
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        print("op shape ", x.shape)
        return x
```

This worked for me!
Hope this might help somebody!
Thank you!